# tar one folder to an other directory

Tags: shell, tar

I'm trying to create a bash script that creates an archive of one folder (or the folder content) to a specific directory.

My version works but instead to archive one folder it archives me the whole path which I don't want.
Is there a way to solve this problem without using cd? I saw some solutions using `-C` but I get the following error, no matter where I place it: `refusing to create an empty archive`

```
SRCDIR=~/Documents/sub1/sub2/sub3/source/*
DESTDIR=~/Documents/sub1/sub2/sub3/target/backup.tgz
tar czf $DESTDIR  --absolute-names  $SRCDIR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SRCDIR=~/Documents/sub1/sub2/sub3/source/*
DESTDIR=~/Documents/sub1/sub2/sub3/target/backup.tgz
tar czf $DESTDIR --absolute-names -C $(dirname $SRCDIR) $(basename $SRCDIR)
```

As you can see in my example I'm using -C option to change the directory in combination with dirname and basename for source directory

```
OTHER OPTIONS

  -C, --directory DIR
       change to directory DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the '-C' is being used, the wild-card expansion does not work well - as it will try to expand the wildcard ('*' in this case) at the current directory where the command is invoked, and NOT at the SRCDIR location.

If you want all files to be included in the repository, use the '.' (it will also include hidden files!).

```
SRCDIR=~/Documents/sub1/sub2/sub3/source/*
DESTDIR=~/Documents/sub1/sub2/sub3/target/backup.tgz
tar czf $DESTDIR -C "$(dirname $SRCDIR)" .
```

As a side note, the original post is using '--absolute-names'. You might want to reconsider using this flag, as it make it extremely difficult to restore the files into any other location but the original location of the files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I only used --absolute-names because I got the following error: tar: Removing leading `/' from

Comment: @ThinkCode. The message is just a warning. You will not get it if you use the proposed solution. I've fixed the posted code to eliminate it.